# Reformatting the table caption and its appearance

Tags: tables, captions

How to make word "Table" aligned right and text of table's caption centered in next line? Also, I need the word "Table" to be centered without the ":"

I tried this:

```
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=off}
```

But it makes all caption aligned right. And it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Can you please provide a full [minimum working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?  It will help us help you.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean flushed to the right margin or to the right-side of the table?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

- See section 4, "Own enhancements", of the user guide of the `caption` package for more information about the `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` macro.
- If you want to show just the label "Table" *without* the table number, you would need to change `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{right}{\hfill#1 #2}` to `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{right}{\hfill#1}`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove "demo" option in real document

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{right}{\hfill#1 #2}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=right,labelsep=newline}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{some caption}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{sample}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```